# Grep all IP address from nslookup

Tags: awk, grep

I'd like to get all IP of google netblock.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-131 ~]# nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8 | grep 'ip4'
```

Here's result:

```
_netblocks.google.com   text = "v=spf1 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip :66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.192.0/19 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"
```

But my expected result is:

```
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
........
```

How can i achieve my goal?

My best effort is only get 1 IP :(

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-131 ~]# nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8 | grep 'ip4' | cut -d: -f3 | awk '{print $1}'
66.102.0.0/20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `--perl-regexp`:

```
$ nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8 | grep -Po 'ip4:\K\S+'
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.80.0/20
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
108.177.8.0/21
173.194.0.0/16
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.239.32.0/19
```

---

- `\K` - discards previous match
- `[^\s]+` - match any sequence except whitespaces

Comment: You saved my day, man. Thanks Roman. Can you please explain about this command?

Comment: Just mind it is not a *Perl* regex, it is a PCRE regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, keep in mind that long option is called `--perl-regexp` (sounds exactly as "perl regexp")

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It does not change the fact no Perl is used in this case. R also uses `perl` argument to parse the pattern with a PCRE regex engine. That is not related to Perl (all Perl users usually take offense when they see "Perl" tag).

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}}' Input_file
```

OR

```
your_command | awk '{while(match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}}'
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Ravinder.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():

```
$ nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8 |
    awk -v RS='ip4:\\S+' 'RT{print gensub(/[^:]+:/,"",1,RT)}'
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.80.0/20
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
108.177.8.0/21
173.194.0.0/16
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.239.32.0/19
```

Comment: awk is so powerful. Thanks Ed.